# GitHub network/meta and network/chunk Error 400 - Bad Request

Tags: javascript, json, http, github, bad-request

I'm trying to get the meta and chunk data of a repository network in GitHub.

I looked inside the source code of the network view of a repository and apparently you can get the meta and chunk data via:

"/user/repo/network/meta"
and
"/user/repo/network/chunk&nethash=NETHASH_HERE".

By debugging the page I found out that the needed nethash for the chunk is inside the meta data. But everytime I enter the URL I get a "Bad Request" even though I copy paste it directly from the debugged network view of a repository (and there it apparently works..).
I also tried using the nethash I got from debugging the page but still a bad request.

As an example I tried [this link](https://github.com/caseypugh/minecraft/network/chunk?nethash=b95a9e6352dc86ba0c712dc294bc16070b7f55d4). It's the request for the chunk data with the nethash parameter.

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So, got a bit smarter...
When I debug the [PAGE](https://github.com/caseypugh/minecraft/network) and inspect the network tab I can see that the 'meta' and 'chunk' requests are there when the site is loaded. Using firefox I can even resend the request and I get a working response.

If I try to use getJSON or a normal XHR (via Javascript or Java, doesnt matter) I get the 'Bad Request - 400' ...

Am I missing something fundamental or is it not possible to get those two queries outside of GitHub?

I'd appreciate any response :/